# How to configure Xmpp library in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, xmpp, ejabberd

I was searching for solution to use xmpp library on flutter to connect with ejabberd server for chatting app. Anyone's suggestion will be very help for me.

Answer (score 3):

XMPP connection made with flutter by using the xmpp_stone library. My Github repository is [here](https://github.com/Nova-Corp/xmpp_ex.git). The main problem is, it connects without tls connection. In your ejabberd configuration yaml file line **starttls: true, starttls_required: true** should be commented.

If you have a better solution please suggest me. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I founded one way to connecting ejabberd server flutter given Strophe library [enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/strophe) Strophe.js is an XMPP library for JavaScript. Its primary purpose is to enable web-based, real-time XMPP applications that run in any browser.